# Tests fail to start using spring-kafka-test (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I am testing a feature that uses a Kafka producer and listener, with the help of `spring-kafka-test`.

Both `spring-kafka` and `spring-kafka-test` are using the [2.8.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka/2.8.2) version.

My test classes use the `@EmbeddedKafka` annotation as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, brokerProperties = { "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092", "port=9092" })
class EmbeddedKafkaIntegrationTest {
    // Test cases
}
```

I get the following stacktrace as I run the tests:

```
Failed to resolve parameter [com.my-company.my-app.kafka.KafkaProducer kafkaProducer] in constructor [public com.my-company.my-app.kafka.DigitalKafkaListenerIT(com.my-company.my-app.kafka.KafkaProducer,com.my-company.my-app.config.ApplicationProperties)]: Failed to load ApplicationContext
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [com.my-company.my-app.kafka.KafkaProducer kafkaProducer] in constructor [public com.my-company.my-app.kafka.DigitalKafkaListenerIT(com.my-company.my-app.kafka.KafkaProducer,com.my-company.my-app.config.ApplicationProperties)]: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:239)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/Reservoir
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/Reservoir
    at org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.impl.DefaultMetricsProvider$DefaultMetricsContext.lambda$getSummary$2(DefaultMetricsProvider.java:126)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codahale.metrics.Reservoir
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 105 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possibly a bug in the [2.8.2 version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka-test/2.8.2) of `spring-kafka-test`.

Switching back to latest minor [2.7.10 version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka-test/2.7.10) solved the issue, even though `spring-kafka` is still on 2.8.2.

Comment: You probably need to upgrade the kafka jars so the right versions are used (same version as kafka-clients. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#update-deps

Comment: I can confirm this. In my case, I observed the same issue after an upgrade of the version of Spring Boot, the project was based on. I was able to resolve it, by removing a fixed version for the kafka-client jars, that I had added before the upgrade.